# Why am I getting this Javascript runtime error?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I've got the following JavaScript on my web page...

```
64    var description = new Array();
65    description[0] = "..."
66    description[1] = "..."
...
78    function init() {
79        document.getElementById('somedivid').innerHTML = description[0];
80    }
81
82    window.onload = init();
```

In Microsoft Internet Explorer it causes the following error...

> A Runtime Error has occurred.
>   Do you wish to debug?
>
> Line: 81
>   Error: Not implemented

[image: javascript runtime error]

Line 79 executes as expected.

If line 79 is commented out, it still throws the error.

If I comment out line 82, then the function does not execute and there is no error.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Shouldn't line 82 read:

```
window.onload = init;
```

When you do "init()" it's a call to a function that returns void. You end up calling that function before the page loads.

Comment: window.onload = init();  Assigns the result of Init to window.onload, which expects a function pointer.  This is the error I think.

Comment: Several good answers.  But, I accept this one because it requires only two key strokes.

Answer (score 2):

To preserve any previously set onload functions try this

```
var prevload = window.onload;
window.onload = function(){
    prevload();
    init();
}
```

Comment: Check to see if prevload is set first:
prevload && prevload();

Comment: You should be using attachEvent/addEventListener instead (and abstracting it if you do it more than once).

Comment: @Ates Goral: If that's what it looks like, that is pretty darn sweet syntactic sugar.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add an envent listener for 'load' instead, or use the declarative syntax `<body onload="init()">`.

EDIT: Additionally, saying `window.onload = init();` sets window.onload to the result of calling `init()`. What you mean is `window.onload = init;` (a lambda expression). This is bad practice still, as it overwrites other things that might be bound to `window.onload`.

Comment: This is fine, actually. The onload event handler will be executed once the window loads.

Comment: I don't see why this deserves a downvote, though. Is it wrong?

Comment: Removing line 82 and updating the body tag as described works.

Comment: You can set the onload handler wherever you like. It could even be the first thing you do inside the first <script> tag under <head>.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the onload fixes proposed here, also check to see if there are multiple elements with that ID, I believe IE will return a collection of all elements with that ID, in which case you would need to select the intended item out of the collection before accessing that property or ensure you are using unique IDs.

Answer (score 0):

Try running it in FireFox with the [FireBug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1843) plugin enabled. This will allow you to debug the javascript